# Python Create unknown number of attribute in a class

Tags: python

I have the following code. I would like to know how I can create an as many attribute for the object `labyrinth` that I have robot. I have two doubts, how to create the attribute and how to call the function. Anyone ? :)

```
class Robot:

    """Class that represents a robot."""

    def __init__(self, name, x, y):
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class Labyrinth:

    """Class that represents a labyrinth."""

    def __init__(self, obstacles, *args):
        self.grid = {}
        for robot in args:  # First doubt
            self.robot.name = [robot.x, robot.y]  # First doubt


robot_1 = Robot(robot_1, 5, 6)
robot_2 = Robot(robot_2, 8, 9)
...
...
...
# unkown number of robots...

labyrinth = Labyrinth(obstacles, ......)  # Second doubt
```

Comment: You should create a list of robots instead of one attribute per robot.

Comment: Can you develop a little bit ? Do you mean to create a list that will contain all my robot and then loop on this list ? Thank you. (At first, it was my idea but I had difficulty to implement it.

Comment: Grille? Nom? You're making me hungry...

Comment: Sorry  wrong translation from french to english. I corrected it. I will pay more attention next time.

Comment: @Tousalouest I've answer you in a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option, using a `list` to store the robots:

```
 class Labyrinth:
    def __init__(self, obstacles, robots):
        self.robots = robots

labyrinth = Labyrinth(obstacles, [robot1, robot2])
```

Second option, using `args` (renamed to `robots` for convenience):

```
 class Labyrinth:
    def __init__(self, obstacles, *robots):
        self.robots = robots

labyrinth = Labyrinth(obstacles, robot1, robot2)
```

Then, you can access each robot's name with `labyrinth.robots[i].name` where `i` is the index of the robot you want.

If you *really* want to use dynamic attributes, you can do the following:

```
class A:    
    def __init__(self, *args):
        for idx, arg in enumerate(args):
            setattr(self, 'arg_' + str(idx), arg)

a = A(1,2,3,4)
print(a.arg_0, a.arg_1, a.arg_2, a.arg_3) # print "1 2 3 4"
```

but I suggest you to not use that.